# VB.NET 1.1 Safely abort thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, abort

I'm trying to safely kill a thread. In my button click I have:

```
try
    dim bar as new foo()
    dim mythread as New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf bar.Start)
    mythread.Start()
    sleep(1000)
    mythread.abort()
catch ex as Exception
    msgbox ex.Message
end try
```

In my Class I have:

```
class foo

public function Start()
        Try
        do some stuff...
        Catch tae As ThreadAbortException
            Thread.ResetAbort()
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogData("[ ERROR ] ", "[ Start ]" & ex.Message & " line: " & Erl())
        End Try
end sub

end class
```

When it goes to abort the thread I still get a thread abort error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't start the thread.  Post code that reproduces this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really impossible to "safely" abort a thread.  You should, instead, focus on having a mechanism where you can notify the thread that it should exit, and allow it to cooperatively exit (via returning from its main entry point method).